# Variant visitation overload trick not working in gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17

I am having trouble using the variant visitation overload trick described [here](https://arne-mertz.de/2018/05/overload-build-a-variant-visitor-on-the-fly/) in gcc. I tried different versions on compiler explorer and none of them works. On the other hand the newest clang versions accept it.

```
template <class... Fs>
struct overload : Fs...
{
    template <class... Ts>
    overload(Ts&& ...ts) : Fs{std::forward<Ts>(ts)}... {}

    using Fs::operator()...;
};

template <class... Ts>
overload(Ts&&...) -> overload<std::remove_reference_t<Ts>...>;


int main()
{
    auto visitor = overload(
        [](int) { },
        [](double) { }
    );
}
```

gives

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'overload<Fs>::overload(Ts&& ...) [with Ts = {func()::<lambda(int)>, func()::<lambda(double)>}; Fs = {}]':
<source>:21:13:   required from here
<source>:7:52: error: mismatched argument pack lengths while expanding 'Fs'

     overload(Ts&& ...ts) : Fs{std::forward<Ts>(ts)}...
                                                    ^~~
Compiler returned: 1
```

it seems that gcc is having trouble with the template deduction guide.

EDIT: I found that replacing the deduction guide by a function template like this

```
template <class... Ts>
overload<std::remove_reference_t<Ts>...> overloaded(Ts&& ...ts)
{
    return overload<std::remove_reference_t<Ts>...>(ts...);
}
```

works, but I would be interested if there is a problem with the deduction guides or if it is a gcc bug?

Comment: According a comment in the page you link, it's a g++ bug.

Comment: Thanks I must have overlooked that. I suspect that the comment is refering to this gcc issue https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80438

Comment: I suppose you're right; if it isn't the correct bug, is another very very similar and, presumably, related.